# How to parse a html in android?

Tags: android

i am new to android and wanted to read data from a url .
MY aim is to parse a one single page of a particular website and store it locally.
i have heared json can be used for this purpose but i am unable to find a suitable article that explains how to read using it.
It would be really helpful if somebody posts a beginner introduction of parsing a web-page in android be it with json or any other technology.
i am programming android in Eclipse IDE

Comment: lets make it more clear — eclipse is an IDE, JSON is a data format. And to parse something you need to use some programming language to write parser or use some that was already written by smart guys.

Comment: i mean that only igor,i mentioned Eclipse Ide as i was working in it for android programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article: [Registering via Intentfilter](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intentfilter).  It illustrates how to get html source from a webpage and display it to the user.  Developed in Eclipse.