# retrieving a specific text from a webpage android studio

Tags: android

I would like to build an app and in the app i want to pull a specific text from a website. So lets say that we want to retrieve and store the words "Connect with friends and the world around you on Facebook" from facebook.com. which is easy to get if i want to get the whole text from a specific website. Now lets say that we would like to get the word connect only or friends only from the website and store it into a string and print it.

what im doing is a currency app and getting the number http://www.hawlergov.org/en/currency.php and retrieving 128,800.

the number then prints out on the textView

[image: img]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a html in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126680/how-to-parse-a-html-in-android)

Comment: [ask] with [mcve]

Comment: Do you really want to parse HTML? There are API just for currency conversion

Comment: the Kurdish / iraq is incorrect on all the websites except the government website.

Comment: <tr><td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc" width="70%">
<img src="../images/dot.png" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><span class="newsHeader"> 100 USA Dollar</span>
</td>
<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ccc" width="30%">
<span class="newsHeader">128,800 IQD</span>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: so i would like to save newsHeader text im assuming and store it in my app and refresh everytime they click convert todays currency

Answer (score 0):

I Answered my own question by splitting the string like this!

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView text;
TextView text2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new doit().execute();
        }
    });


}

public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String words;
    String currentString;
    String date;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.hawlergov.org/en/currency.php").get();
            words = doc.text();
            currentString = words;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String first = words;
        String roar = first.substring(718, 730);



        words=roar;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        text2.setText(currentDate);
        text.setText(words);
    }


}
```

[here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IuYu.png)